# scikit-learn（決定木回帰）のAPIについて

Tags: python, 機械学習

scikit-learn の決定木を使った回帰についての質問です。

同アルゴリズムでは、
予測の精度を表す.score と
特徴量の重要性を表す .features_importances_　が
あるかと思いますが、
回帰においてはそれぞれどのように算出されているのでしょうか？

分類であれば、前者は正しく分類できた割合
後者は不純度を大きく下げた特徴量ということになると記憶していますが・・・
回帰においてはどのように表現されるのでしょうか？

ご鞭撻いただけると幸いです。

Comment: OSSなんだから「どう計算されているか」なんてコードを見れば一発だと思いますよ。

Answer (score 0):

feature importancesは[ジニ重要度](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.feature_importances_)、scoreは[R^2スコア](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.score)です。
実際にどう計算されているかという話なら、ソースコードを見ることができます。

- compute_feature_importances: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/5572a342bb315787621b1ce894b36987a10a855c/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx#L1076
- r2_score: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/37ac6788c9504ee409b75e5e24ff7d86c90c2ffb/sklearn/metrics/_regression.py#L702